# Unable to update complete child object in Firebase Java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have two **classes** :

```
@Data
public static class Person {
    private String id;
    private String value;
    private Address address;

}

@Data
public static class Address {
    private String add1;
    private String add2;
}

@Test
void name2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    final Person p = new Person();
    p.setId("2FEpIFGqH7izWJ1ydfaKtg");
    p.setValue("some-value");

    final Address address = new Address();
    address.setAdd1("Add 1");
    address.setAdd2("Add 2");
    p.setAddress(address);

    final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("address", address);

    firestore.collection("test").document("2FEpIFGqH7izWJ1ydfaKtg").update(params).get();

    // firestore.collection("test").document("2FEpIFGqH7izWJ1ydfaKtg").set(params, SetOptions.merge()).get(); This also doesn't works, I get same error.
}
```

I get the following **error** when I run this code:

```
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: Cannot convert CustomerRepositoryTest.Address(add1=Add 1, add2=Add 2) to Firestore Value
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException.invalidState(FirestoreException.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.UserDataConverter.encodeValue(UserDataConverter.java:178)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.fromObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.UpdateBuilder.performUpdate(UpdateBuilder.java:513)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.UpdateBuilder.update(UpdateBuilder.java:347)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference.update(DocumentReference.java:231)
```

However, I am able to update partial data setting up value for **add1** by reaching out to the document by path: `/test/<ID>/address.add1`

I want a mechanism to **update the complete object** and not just specific value.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and please also indicate the exact line of code at which that error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

To write an entire object, use `ref.set(p)`. This will overwrite any existing data at `ref` with the data in `p`.

There is no way to write a subset of the data of an object to a location. If you need that functionality, you'll need to create a `Map` with the specific fields you want to update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it wasn't fulfilling my requirement, instead of updating only Address it was also setting other values to null.

But I found the solution after your suggestion, In order to update a child object we will need to use SetOptions.merge(fieldNames).

```code
firestore.collection("test").document("EpIFGqH7izWJ1ydfaKtg").set(test, SetOptions.mergeFields("address")).get();
```

Comment: Interesting. Might be worth it if you post a self-answer with the update code when using that API.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured out the solution:

```
@Test
void name2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    final Person p = new Person();

    final Address address = new Address();
    address.setAdd1("Add 1");
    address.setAdd2("Add 2");
    p.setAddress(address);

    final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("address", address);

    firestore.collection("test").document("2FEpIFGqH7izWJ1ydfaKtg").set(test, SetOptions.mergeFields("address")).get();

}
```

By using **SetOptions.mergeFields()** and providing fields to be updated I was able to update specified fields.

Comment: Glad to see that worked. Just in addition I will share this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions) about this 'firebase.firestore.SetOptions'. Also I recommend you that you accept your own answer.